# Auto commit sideloaded changes on other records with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, commit, ember-data, sideloading

I have a application where a User has one Team.

I am on the form where you create a new team. When I create a team, my api returns the json of the new team and also returns some json of its owner user, because creating a team changes a flag in the user.

```
{
  "team": {
    "id":139,
    "name":"myteam",
    "manager_nickname":"Miguel",
    "stadium_name":"riazr",
    "user_id":10,
    "next_match_id":null,
    "kit_id":139
  },
  "users":[
    {
      "id":10,
      "team_ready":true
    }
  ]
}
```

My application creates transaction when the controller is initialized and calls createRecord on to fill the controller's model.
The attributes of this model are automatically filled with bindings to the form fields.
The submit action validates some fields in the client side and if all seems correct, commits the transaction.

Here the code:

```
App.TeamsNewController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin,{
  // Validations
  //
  // ..code omitted..

  // Bindings
  //
  // ..code omitted..

  // Observers
  //
  transitionAfterSave: function(){
    if (this.get('model.id')){
      //
      // At this point the team has been successfully saved.
      // App.get('currentTeam.isDirty') # => false
      // App.get('currentUser.isDirty') # => true
      //
      // The transaction committed the changes in the team record. Committing those
      // changes bring some other changes to the team's user via side-load, and those
      // changes are not commited yet.
      //
      // I can understand it, since the commit was made before these data where
      // returned, but I think that it should be a way to autocommit changes from
      // sideloaded data.
      // If commit a change returns side-loaded data from the server, this data should
      // be commited as well. Server's word is sacred, isn't it?
      //
      var team = this.get('model');
      App.set('currentUser.team', team);
      App.set('currentTeam', team);
      this.transitionToRoute('dashboard');
    }
  }.observes('model.id'),

  // Actions
  //
  // This function is called in the #setupController method of the route
  //
  buildTeam: function(){
    this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
    var team = this.transaction.createRecord(
      App.Team,
      { managerNickname: App.get('currentUser.firstName') }
    );
    this.set('model', team);
  },

  submit: function() {
    var controller = this;
    this.validate().then(function(){
      if (controller.get('isValid')){
        controller.transaction.commit();
        controller.transaction = null;
      }
    });
  }

});
```

As I say in the comment, there is a way to have the sideloaded changes in other record autocommited?

Answer (score 0):

Auto response:

It was my mistake. The problem was not in ember not commiting the data received from the server. This data don't marks the record as dirty.

```
  transitionAfterSave: function(){
    if (this.get('model.id')){
      var team = this.get('model');


      App.set('currentUser.team', team);
      // Was this line the one that marked the record as dirty.
      // I realized that the current user was not automatically caching the team
      // identity map mechanism as the own. I didn't gave importance to this and
      // just stablished the relation manually. BAD IDEA
      // Identity map should recognise automatically the relation.
      // The problem was in the json. I added a team_id: XXX key on the side
      // loaded data of the user, all worked.
      // Is still strange to me to send foreign_keys that don't really exist in the 
      // database (is team the one that has a user_id field) and I didn't realized
      // that ember is a different world.
      // 
      // Now this line has gone and all works.


      App.set('currentTeam', team);
      this.transitionToRoute('dashboard');
    }
  }.observes('model.id')
```